# Login error in Ubuntu

Tags: login, error-handling

When i login to Ubuntu, it shows black screen and  says x numbers of file blocked , and then i am again back to login screen. I tried to fix error by pressing ctrl + alt + f4, to use terminal but when i started to write command ,again " The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable." this type of error occured , so i am not able to fix problems with command.
So i thought to proceed using advanced option in boot menu , but when i press f12 and enter to choose option for boot and then when i select ubuntu then it directly starts and takes me to login page, so I can't see recovery mode etc because it doesn't allow me to go to that option
.

Comment: Please someone help me  i am unable to use my computer and without login i wouldn't do anything .

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system & explore from there.  Alternatively if still running I would look in /bin to see that the contents haven't disappeared and look at your $PATH (the variable mentioned in your post text).  If it's not running, I'd though boot a 'live' system & check health of your hdd/ssd (smartctl, `gnome-disks` KDE Partition Manager etc) then `fsck` your partition, then `mount` and explore looking for issues, did you change a .bash* file in your ~, does /bin etc look normal etc.  If `fsck` found issues, you can probably boot normally, but I'd act on what I saw...